# SQLalchemy making errors after being updated to 1.4.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils

(Not a question)

I've experienced some crashes with `sqlalchy_utils` after updating from sqlalchemy 1.3.21 to 1.4.0.

Just deprecate it to 1.3.xx.

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_ColumnEntity' from 'sqlalchemy.orm.query' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py)
```

Answer (score 1):

`sqlalchemy_utils` is currently not compatible with SQLAlchemy > 1.4.0:

[Temporarily require sqlalchemy <1.4.0 to make compatible with sqlalchemy-utils](https://github.com/cesium-ml/baselayer/pull/205)